# Convert NSString in MM-dd-yy format to NSDate

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

In my application I am getting an NSString with the date as 01-22-12(MM-dd-yy). Now I want to convert that string into an NSDate. I used the code below. But it is giving the date as 2012-01-04 05:00:00 +0000

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yy"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:self.selectedWeek];
```

What is the proper way to convert my string to an NSDate?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you want exactly?

Comment: need nsdate value with same format.

Answer (score 1):

From your original question I'm not totally clear whether you want:

1 the string as an `NSDate`.

or

2 to be able to get the original date `NSString` back out of an `NSDate` instance.

Your code is basically right.  I just ran a slightly adapted version of it, which seemed to work fine:

```
NSString *dateString = @"01-22-12";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yy"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSString *outString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

NSLog(@"%@",date);
NSLog(@"%@",outString);
```

This produced:

```
2013-02-24 09:57:24.352 datesAgain.m.out[787:707] 2012-01-22 00:00:00 +0000
2013-02-24 09:57:24.352 datesAgain.m.out[787:707] 01-22-12
```

So, either way the result seems to be what you were looking for. I suspect that the reason you are getting an incorrect value is that `self.selectedWeek` doesn't have the value you think it does. I'd inspect it, either in the debugger or with `NSLog`.  If you are creating it somewhere else using another format string, be aware that they can be tricky and slightly unintuitive - for instance `s` means seconds, but `S` means fractions of a second.
Documentation available [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1) - most recent Unicode formatting standard [here](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns) (ios6.0/OSX 10.8) - also linked to in previous link, as are all previous relevant standards

Comment: I need the date value also in outstring format means 01-22-12.And i want to send that value as argument for method.Iam using that value to write the query for getting the values from database using that date.One of the column datatype is Date.I want to pass this value to that field.

Comment: O.K. So the answer is 2. You'll need to work out what format the db requires for a date, produce a string in that format and interpolate it into the query. Is '01-22-12' correct for your db? If so the code above should work- you can just interpolate `outString`. If not, you could create a second `NSDateFormatter` and use the resources linked to above to produce a date string in the correct format, set it as the format string, and produce a string that the db will accept

Comment: Yes,I need the date in 01-22-12 format only.So how can i interpolate that outstring.

Comment: Use `-stringWithFormat:...` - e.g `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT COLS FROM TABLE WHERE DATE = %@",dateString];`. Use `-utf8String` on this if the db needs a C String. You can also use `%@` to interpolate the column names and table name as variables- but be aware that this might leave you open to SQL injection attacks, depending on how the functions are used in your app. If you are using the `sqlite` C API there are special functions for assembling C String queries- docs here http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use [descriptionWithCalendarFormat:timeZone:locale:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/descriptionWithCalendarFormat%3atimeZone%3alocale%3a)

```
NSString * mydate =  [dateFromString descriptionWithCalendarFormat:@"%Y-%m-%d"
                                timezone:nil
                                  locale:nil];
```

Comment: But i need that value in NSdate object.

Comment: the dateFromString is your converted date so this will return the your NSDate object

Comment: But u assigned to nsstring.